# Slidetoggle on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle, shopp

I am working on jquery and I am trying to use slideToggle on dynamic content but I cannot make it up slide. How could make it work properly? I will provide you the http://jsfiddle.net/P3WaC/

```
<li class="pull-right">
<div class="text-righ padding-right">
    <div class="chart">My cart (<span class="item_cart">3</span>)</div>
    <button class="btn btn-warning">CHECKOUT</button>
    <input type="text" class="input-large light-panel active-tab-search" placeholder="Search rewards">
</div>
<div id="cart-info" style="display: none;">
    <div id="each-2" class="shopp" style="display: none;">
        <div class="label">Gift voucher</div>
        <div class="shopp-price">$<span class="itempr">20</span>
        </div><span>Quantity: </span><span class="shopp-quantity">2</span>
        <img src="../img/erop/remove.png" class="remove">
        <br class="all">
    </div>
    <div id="each-3" class="shopp" style="display: none;">
        <div class="label">Gift voucher</div>
        <div class="shopp-price">$<span class="itempr">10</span>
        </div><span>Quantity: </span><span class="shopp-quantity">1</span>
        <img src="../img/erop/remove.png" class="remove">
        <br class="all">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.pull-right').on('click',function(){
    alert( $('#cart-info').text()); 
    $('#cart-info').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

The dynamic content is under cart-info. I want to display the items and hide them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display:none;` off the child div's of `#cart-info`, or else they won't show!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/P3WaC/1/

Comment: Precisely these ones: `<[...] class="shopp" style="display: none;">`

Comment: Thank you tymeJV! I was confused! I realized it :)

Comment: @epapath -- No problem...I was a bit confused as to why it wasn't working at first as well, then I saw it :D

Answer (score 1):

Just show the `.shopp` elements before sliding the parent:

```
$('.pull-right').on('click',function(){
    alert( $('#cart-info').text()); 
    $('#cart-info').find('.shopp').show();  //added line
    $('#cart-info').slideToggle('slow');

});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P3WaC/2/

Comment: I dont know which answer you finally chose, but you should accept one at least.

Comment: Both answers were great! Thank you guys! :)

Comment: @epapath you still have to accept one on the left of each answer, the green Tick...

Comment: I know that my friend but I got the first answer. But your answer is very good also. I am working it out what approach I will use. Thank you very much both of you.

Comment: @epapath I didn't see the other answer marked as valid. Now I do. Is fine.